# Getting the relative date from a Timestamp (i.e. Today, Tomorrow)

Tags: php, date, time

I was wondering if PHP has a built in function to return the relevance of a date. For example:

```
$timestamp = time();
$other = time()+86400;

echo rel_date($timestamp); //prints Today
echo rel_date($other); //prints Tomorrow
```

I know it's pretty simple functionality to build but I don't want to be reinventing the wheel!

Comment: start from [`DateTime::diff` — Returns the difference between two DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: If relevance would be defined sth like a 'closeness' to today, i would use sth like relevance(curr, other) = 1 / (diffdays(curr, other)+1)^2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built in function that has a format option which ouputs "Today", "Yesterday", "Tomorrow", etc..

I've made them myself because of this anyway. It seems you'll need to build it yourself after all, sorry :(